# android, is fragment's getArguments() always returns the arguments set for this fragment, even after the fragment is destroyed?

Tags: android-fragments

Having the TestFragment created with arguments set:

```
arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…]
```

Since it is newly instantiated, so the `savedInstanceState==null` at `onCreate()`:

```
04-24 09:05:33.645 24998-24998/test I/+++: +++ TestFragment{af43958 #0 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onCreateView(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…], savedInstanceState==null ==> true
04-24 09:05:33.646 24998-24998/test I/+++: +++ TestFragment{af43958 #0 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onActivityCreated(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…], savedInstanceState==null ==> true
```

minimize the app,   the  `onDestroy()` is called:

```
04-24 09:05:48.558 24998-24998/test V/+++: +++ TestFragment{af43958 #0 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onSaveInstanceState(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…]
04-24 09:05:48.695 24998-24998/test E/+++: +++ --- TestFragment{af43958 #0 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onDestroyView(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…]
04-24 09:05:48.707 24998-24998/test E/+++: +++ --- --- TestFragment{af43958 #0 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onDestroy(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…]
```

Re-open the app,  os restores the fragment with `savedInstanceState` not null,  but the `arguments` is still having its previous value

```
arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…]
```

These are the log when os restores the fragment with the arguments:

```
04-24 09:06:02.579 24998-24998/test I/+++: +++ TestFragment{cc4d10c #2 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onCreateView(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…], savedInstanceState==null ==> false
04-24 09:06:02.579 24998-24998/test I/+++: +++ TestFragment{cc4d10c #2 id=0x7f0a00f5}::onActivityCreated(), arguments: Bundle[{key=value Paris}…], savedInstanceState==null ==> false
```

How is the fragment’s arguments stored,  will it have same life cycle as the bundle saved with the savedInstanceState?

Or does it meant as long as there is something withe the `arguments` it should not (or no need to) be saved to `savedInstanceState`?

Comment: Arguments survives just like the saved instance state Bundle, yes. Same behavior as with Intents, and it is expected behavior.

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce, so the arguments lives outside of the Fragment and will be kept even after the Fragment is destroyed (in the case os will recreate the Fragment).   does it relate to setRetainInstance(boolean retain) and behavior differently with true or false set?

Comment: It actually doesn't change behavior in regards to retain instance. You'll still get a fragment recreation with `savedInstanceState != null` after process death.